# Control automatically imported modules

Tags: python, configuration

Basically, I am cramming python into an embedded environment where I can't compile/configure it on the system itself.  I am not surprised that the `site` module refuses to load; but that's okay, I don't need it. **How do I control which modules python automatically imports?**

Notes, this is a [static build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150373/compile-the-python-interpreter-statically), and the only things I've copied to the working environment from the host are my static executable, and the contents of my /usr/lib/python/ directory (.py files) aka, no config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting Python with the `-S` flag suppresses the automatic importing of the `site` module.  Others, such as `signal` and `readline`, are actually built in. So you can just use the `-S` flag and then in your main script import what you need. Make sure you at least call `sys.setdefaultencoding("ascii")` (or "utf-8") early.