# Building a static version of Python on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: python, gcc, build, static-libraries, static-linking

After looking at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150373/compile-the-python-interpreter-statically), it appears that I am supposed to be able to build a static version of Python thusly:

```
./configure --disable-shared LDFLAGS="-static -static-libgcc" CPPFLAGS="-static"
```

However, running `make` configured as above eventually barfs up some warnings and an error:

```
gcc -pthread -static -static-libgcc -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python \
            Modules/python.o \
            libpython2.7.a -lpthread -ldl  -lutil   -lm  
<SNIP>
libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_initgroups':
Python-2.7.2/./Modules/posixmodule.c:3981: warning: Using 'initgroups' in
statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared
libraries from the glibc version used for linking

/usr/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp' with pointer equality in
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libc.a(strcmp.o)'
can not be used when making an executable;
recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm stuck. It appears to be asking me to recompile libc. I thought `-static-libgcc` would be enough, but apparently it is not. Does anyone know what is going on here, and how to achieve my goal of building a static python on Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: While building a different binary, I had this same error.  I overcame the error by adding "-Wl,--no-export-dynamic" to the LDFLAGS.