# Statically linked python on Windows

Tags: python, windows

I need a python interpreter to be statically linked to my app (Windows app) that means, that I need no dlls with my app. My app will not use any third-party python modyles, only text scripts.

How can I do this? Or may be there are already compiled libs?

A need a 3.2 version of python

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150373/compile-the-python-interpreter-statically

Comment: Not really, as the question you mention is Linux/UNIX specific, even though it doesn't say so explicitly in the title nor in the question itself.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood That's a Linux answer, this question is about doing this on Windows; are you sure the other question would provide sufficient information?

Comment: Sorry missed the Linux vs Windows difference.  It might still be helpful though.

Answer (score -1):

Due to how the Windows loader works, this is impossible; DLLs loaded by the app (including .pyd files) do **not** have access to the symbol table used/provided by the executable by default, and so must read the symbols from the pythonX.Y.dll instead.

Comment: That's impossible even if my app will not load any additional .pyd's? I just need python script to call functions exported by app. python will be a scripting language. So, no additional libs