# Relocatable (self-contained) Python built from source tarball inside virtualenv environment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I have looked at the `virtualenv` documentation and also found [this question here at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249901). However, neither answer my question or I may be missing something, so I am asking.

How can I create a `virtualenv` environment which contains a `python` that doesn't depend on the (system-wide) `python` of the "host"? I.e. I want a fully self-contained `virtualenv` with its own Python 2.7 compiled from source. Another property would be important: since `virtualenv` isn't the same as `chroot` the `python` inside the `virtualenv` has to cope with different absolute paths.

I reckon the closest to what I want is a `virtualenv --relocatable` with its own Python installation inside.

How can I achieve that?

#### Rationale

I have some older Linux boxes with different versions of Python offered through the package manager. The admin won't allow me to build a more recent Python on the boxes, so I need to be able to install a Python from source into the constrained environment I have.

#### Properties I need:

- `virtualenv` environment should be *fully* self-contained (complete Python with all libraries etc)
- the `python` inside should work regardless of its absolute path when deployed

  - I'm aware the `$ENV/bin/python` seems to do that, but it also seems to rely on the `python` installed system-wide. I want to cut this dependency out completely, rolling my own Python.
- Should behave like with `virtualenv --relocatable` but needs to **contain** a full Python installation as well.

#### Issues that can be ignored for the scope of this question:

- Architecture/platform. This will run only on a single architecture and the `virtualenv` environment will be built for each platform (currently only various Linux distros).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. get the python source
2. `./configure --prefix=/dest`
3. `make && make install`

congratulations, you now have a python installation that's completely independent of the system python in `/dest`. Moving this directory shouldn't be a problem, if that's what you mean with 'relocatable'.

To use this installation instead of the system python, just make sure to put `/dest/bin` on the `PATH` before the standard locations.

If that's not enough for you, you can setup a virtualenv using this python installation...

Comment: so far my built Python disagrees with the assertion that it should be relocatable. But I'll keep trying a little further.

Comment: What additional steps did you need to perform to get your 'relocatable' python distribution?

Comment: Do you mean "make && make install" ? :)

Comment: What happens when you pip install something which installs an executable script?  For example if you install youtube-dl or pygments or something, it'll work where you first install it but then you cannot move the install somewhere else.

Comment: This is not a relocatable build. sysconfig gets its prefix stored at build time, and if you then move to another location on disk the prefixes won't match (this is particularly problematic with anything that requires linking against `libpython`).