# How to static link to python library correctlly?

Tags: python, c++, gcc, boost

I've built the static python using this tutorial:(python version 3.4.2)

> [Compile the Python interpreter statically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150373/compile-the-python-interpreter-statically)

Everything works ,well almost. when My simple test application link with the library:

> libpython3.4m.a

This is the source code of the simple demo:

```
using namespace boost::python;
using namespace std;

class World {
private:
    string name;
public:
    void set(string name) {
        this->name = name;
    }
    void greet() {
        printf("name is %s\n", this->name.c_str());
    }
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr< World > world_ptr;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello) {
    class_<World>("World")
    .def("greet", &World::greet)
    .def("set", &World::set)
    ;
};
int main ( int argc, char** argv ) {


    Py_NoSiteFlag = 1;
    Py_FrozenFlag = 1;
    //Py_IgnoreEnvironmentFlag = 1;


    Py_SetPythonHome(L".");
    Py_SetProgramName(L"");

    PyImport_AppendInittab("hello",PyInit_hello);

    Py_Initialize();

    try {


        PyRun_SimpleStringFlags("import hello", NULL);
        PyRun_SimpleStringFlags("ha = hello.World()", NULL);
        PyRun_SimpleStringFlags("ha.set('tango')", NULL);
        PyRun_SimpleStringFlags("ha.greet()", NULL);

    }
    catch(error_already_set) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is here that When I run the demo,it says :

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Then I copy Lib directory from python directory to the demo directory,then before I run my application I export this:

```
export PYTHONPATH="Lib/"
```

Then the problem has gone,but here is the question:

```
Can I compile all the package in the Lib to static library libpython3.4m.a? so that I don't have to carry Lib files?
```

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this problem?