# How to fine-tune where a binary looks for its shared libraries during configure/build (linux)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, configuration

Although my issue is related to building Python, it could be considered generic. I have built Python with a custom `TclTk` installation, using `--with-tcltk-includes` and `--with-tcltk-libs`. Say I passed `/foo/bar/spam` path to the latter. The problem is, when I use `strace` to check where the binary looks for its shared libraries, I see `/foo/bar/spam` in the search path, although I do not want that because this application will be shipped and this path does not exist anywhere else beyond my own machine. So I want to use it just during the build, but not as a search path for the generated binary. Any ideas?

Comment: Use static linking?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That would probably do, is it possible to static link a specific library using `LDFLAGS`?

Answer (score 0):

Static linking is probably your best bet, because you likely can't guarantee that your customers will have any of the other required libraries (like `sqlite3`, for example) either. Just *don't* pass the flag `--enable-shared` to `./configure` and it will build a statically-linked lib by default.

Unfortunately, I don't see a way with the standard options to build a partial-static/partial dynamic lib. That doesn't mean it isn't possible with some creative tinkering with the `Makefile`, but conceptually I'm not sure how it would work anyway.

Comment: I agree with the overall direction you are going but, although I have not tried your solution yet, some other threads suggest that building Python statically requires a bit more work (consider checking this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150373/compile-the-python-interpreter-statically) and [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildStatically) Python wiki post on building statically). What do you think?

Comment: @luizbarcelos [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1150373) question you linked (haha) and most of its answers are from 2009 (one is from 2015), and I suspect the Python wiki entry is from about that era, as well. Things have changed a LOT since then. I just downloaded the 3.9.7 source on my Linux server, ran `./configure --prefix=$HOME && make` and it produced the `python` binary and a `libpython3.9.a` statically-linked library. No fuss, no bother. Maybe I'll update the Python wiki page at some point...